# SRAM replacement dub crankset, is this pre-greased?

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, sram

I'm replacing the NX cranks on my bike with X01 cranks, all of the install videos I've seen show people greasing the cranks but these look like they're pre-greased. There's blue/green stuff on the spindle and brown inside the socket on the crank as per the pictures.

Is this grease and is this sufficient? Should remove it and replace it with this grease I have?
My old spindle didn't seem to have very much grease at all and it was black so difficult to compare.

[image: New spindle]
[image: New crank arm]
[image: Grease]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is grease, in my opinion that is about the bear minimum amount intended to help prevent seizing between the two interfaces. I usually leave it if it is my own bike and just add a bit more additional grease, as *most* cycling greases will not have any interaction with each other. In a professional setting or working on someone else's bike I would remove it and use all one type.

If you watch Sram's installation videos they are definitely a bit more liberal with the application spreading it both on the exterior of the spindle, and in the grooves that interface with the crankset.

[image]

Comment: It should do no harm, especially in the groves, as it will prevent seizing.

Comment: Shout to to SRAM for applying different amounts of different coloured grease in different ways here. Small amount of blue green on the spindle on arrival vs applying a lot of red themselves on the installation video, that's part of what confused me. Much rather they sent the cranks without and gave you a tube of red grease to self apply.

Comment: @ChrisFletcher it is a bit odd/silly. I would just add a bit extra, throw it together, get on with your life and go ride!

Comment: Better a small amount of grease from the factory in the two most important spots than no grease at all by the person who installs the part.